# Send errors from rails clockwork gem to airbrake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clockwork

What is the best way to send errors from clockwork to Airbrake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following to your clockwork definition:

```
module Clockwork
  error_handler do |error|
    Airbrake.notify_or_ignore(error)
  end

  # existing configuration
end
```

See: [Clockwork Docs about `error_handler`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/clockwork/2.0.0#error_handler)

Answer (score 2):

The airbrake library has an API to notify their service directly without raising an exception. Their GitHub has a ton of documentation on this.

[Airbrake Ruby](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby)

You can do something like this:

```
Airbrake.notify("Opps!")
```